# Filenotfounderror when trying to open a csv file in python

Tags: python, opencsv

I know there are already posts like this but i cant find a solution (new to programming).

I am programming with python using Spyder as interpreter.
i am trying to open/read a file in python using either the standard open()/read() functions or even numpy.loadtxt() (its a csv file that I am trying to open)

Consistently the output i get is a file not found error.

By importing sys and printing sys.path i verified what are the paths python checks when im trying to import something. If i manually cut and paste the file in one of the folders that these paths indicate, the error persists.

On top of the page, spyder gives me the path of the directory im currently programming my file in. I cut and paste the file into the exact same directory where my code is but the problem persists.

I have tried both of the above using the file name as well as putting r'entire path' but still nothing.

Please can you help? Also, being new to programming, if you give me some code to try would you mind just explaining what it means cause a lot of time on stack overflow i see solutions that I simply dont understand.

thanks guys! xx

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and Python programming. Even though your problem is fairly simple and only about a few commands, you should always include some code that shows what you are doing, so people can propose changes that might fix it. Just a single example that reproduces the problem for you should be enough. You can use triple backticks to format a code block.

Comment: Have you tried importing `sys` and then `print(os.getcwd())`? This prints the 'current working directory' for your script, which may be different from the project directory your script and source file are in. By the way, Spyder isn't running as your interpreter, that'll still be an installation of Python itself somewhere on your computer, Spyder just acts as an editor and can show you a command line interface to Python.

Answer (score 0):

`sys.path` is what matters for `import`.
But for `open`, [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd) is what you care about:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

Also, you might consider using a fully specified pathname, rather than a relative one:

```
from pathlib import Path
print(Path('~/Desktop/example.csv').expanduser())
```